# Is there an easy way to switch PHP versions while developing?

Tags: php

I love [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (ruby version manager), it allows to switch quickly between Ruby versions on the command line, like this:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

Is there a similiar tool for PHP? (Preferably on the command line.) I'm currently developing a PHP framework, so I quickly need to test the code on different PHP version.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: nothing like rvm exists for PHP :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply install different versions on PHP, each in a different directory, then use the one you want. You can even make a simple script to automate this (it would run the PHP executable from the directory corresponding to an argument, and/or it could change the Apache configuration to use the specified version and reload Apache).

Comment: I need to build PHP from source if I want to specify the installation directory, right?

Comment: @dotweb, that's what I'd do, since I can easily control what goes into the compiled version, plus I can get access to the latest versions that are not necessarily available in the Linux distribution's repositories. The repositories usually have only a certain version for each brach, or just a single version available, which might not even be the latest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. :) Seems like a nice solution, but it's a pity a rvm like tool doesn't exist.

Comment: @dotweb, `rvm` is indeed convenient, since it pretty much does the same thing, but automated.

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple version of php on your machine in different path and on your script file add the version you want to load at the begining

```
#!/usr/bin/php-4
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/php-5
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[phpenv](https://github.com/CHH/phpenv) is based on [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and offers the ability to switch between PHP versions:

```
$ phpenv global 5.3.11
```

Combined with [php-build](https://github.com/chh/php-build), it's a lot easier to automate building of customized PHP environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch php7.1 to php5.6

first disable the current version 7.1 using below command

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
```

Now enable php5.6

```
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

restart the server and now you ready to go with php5.6

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

same you can do to switch different version of php.